# How can I set CPU affinity for a device driver in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, services, affinity

Does anybody know how to set on which core a device driver will run and process its interrupt requests?

Situation:
I'm having iusb3hcs.sys and acpi.sys causing lags when my soundcard processes realtime audio. Is there a way, to make these two and the soundcard driver run on different processor cores, and to not disturb each other?
We can easily set affinity and priority for a process, but how to do it with a device driver?

And by the way, how can one set affinity to a service running in the background?

P.S.
Soundcard is NOT connected to the usb-3 port, driver of which is causing lags. I can disable this port in the device manager and it works fine. However my mouse is connected to that port and it's really inconvenient to work with the touchpad. So I need the port on and iusb3hcs running to have mouse.

Comment: No;  There is no way to set the affinity of a device driver in Windows.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible on an CPU architecture level. it would imply that a thread could never change cores, so if multiple threads were created on a core, they could never run in parallel, but would instead be constantly context switching. then what is the point of having multiple cores. no I believe that interrupts are socket or system level, so they can reach their thread, regardless of where it is running at any given millisecond. Also note that MS purposely degrades soundcard performance with certain network operations (and usb is a network stack).

Comment: At least for Win2000 there was and application: http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Set-processor-affinity-for-a-device-driver The file is even hosted on MS ftp!

Comment: Hello @FrankThomas, can you give me more specific information on "MS purposely degrades soundcard performance with certain network operations"? Why is that so?

Comment: because they both run over the southbridge, which is a shared bus. many motherboards can't keep up with simultaneous gigabit network performance and 48K audio playback at the same time.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Close, but interrupts aren't handled by threads. When you're running in an ISR you're running in the context of whatever thread happened to be running when the interrupt happened. There is no thread context switch.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan, so when an instruction executing as part of a thread makes a DMA request for data in secondary storage, and pauses, waiting until an IRQ indicating that the DMA request has been fufilled, you claim that the thread does not receive execution time again, as the result of the IRQ? that the data from the DMA event would be given to another unrelated thread, just because it was executing at the second the DMA operation completed? that would not work. and if there were no threaded context switching, DMA would have no point. not really getting what you are saying.

Comment: @FrankThomas No. I said that there is no thread context switch for the ISR. Most certainly, it is not guaranteed to run in the context of the thread that requested the I/O, as that thread is very commonly waiting for the I/O to complete. Interrupts by themselves do not resolve thread waits. That happens when the driver calls, from its DPC routine, IoCompleteRequest. (The DPC routine does not run in requesting thread context either.) When and on which CPU the thread runs on after that is up to the thread scheduler. See the WDK docs; especially look up the term "arbitrary thread context".

Comment: Microsoft's page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547969(v=vs.85).aspx says: "Starting with Windows Vista, administrators can use the registry to set an affinity policy for an interrupt." Haven't delved into details, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can if your soundcard drivers has support for MMCSS: "Multimedia Class Scheduler Service". I have no idea if ASIO for all drivers support this. I have only seen support for this with RME drivers.
With this service enabled, you can with programs like Processes Lasso, modify/change affinity for any cpu core, including hyper threading, for the MMCSS, it is possible that programs that have MMCSS support will work with this too, I have not tried...
It really works and is one important part of how I made my win7 system realtime audio compatible.

Comment: It's not super clear in your answer HOW to set this affinity. Can you please edit your answer to clarify how you set this up? Use formatting and ordered lists to help make any specific steps very clear.